# Не обновляются переменные в самописной функции поиска и замены

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Написал код который должен находить определенный "ключ" в ФайлШаблоне и заменять его на соответствующее значение из ФайлсДанными, при этом сохраняя ФайлШаблон как новый документ excel.
Код, шаблон и таблицу с данными прилагаю(ниже).

Проблема в том, что функция запоминает только переменные  1-ой строки из ФайлсДанными, и вставляет их во все новые файлы. А должна вроде вставлять с каждой последующей строки из ФайлсДанными.

Если просто выводить на печать(print), то все норм, а при использовании функции - проблема.

В чем может быть дело?

таблица с данными:https://yadi.sk/i/JcXPSlUjJcGYog

шаблон: https://yadi.sk/i/RsxcuUBdbYVTNQ

P.s. ошибка в том, что функция find_and_replace в цикле for вызывается лишь при первой итерации. Но я не понимаю почему и как это можно исправить...

Код:

```
import openpyxl
import docxtpl
import os

#открываем ФайлсДанными и ФайлШаблон
wbData = openpyxl.load_workbook('Шаблоны\Таблица с данными.xlsx')
wbTemp = openpyxl.load_workbook('Шаблоны\шаблон.xlsx')
#открываем лист с данными
sheetShablon = wbData['Данные']
#открываем оба листа ФайлШаблон
sheet1 = wbTemp['1']
sheet2 = wbTemp['2']


#!!!Проблемная!!! функция для поиска и замены по ключам
def find_and_replace(sheet, find, replace):    
    for row in sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == find:
                cell.value = replace


#ожидаем от пользователя количество строк с данными
stroki = int(input("Введите количество строк "))



#поиск ключей в ФайлШаблон и замена на значения с ФайлсДанными:
for i in range(stroki):
    #sheet1
    find_and_replace(sheet1,',1,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 1).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet1,',2,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 2).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet1,',3,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 3).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet1,',4,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 4).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet1,',5,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 5).value)
    
    #### sheet2
    find_and_replace(sheet2,',1,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 1).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet2,',2,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 2).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet2,',3,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 3).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet2,',4,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 4).value)
    find_and_replace(sheet2,',5,',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 5).value)
    
    #сохраняем шаблон как новый файл
    wbTemp.save(str(i+1)+'. '+str(sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 10).value)+'.xlsx')
    print('конец строки')
    #и так для каждой строки в файле с данными



print('end')
```

Comment: У вас одна и та же ссылка и на файл с таблицей и на шаблон.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. Ошибку нашел, проблема в том, что функция вызывается лишь при первой итерации и все, в дальнейших итерациях эта функция не вызывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция прекрасно вызывается на всех итерациях, я это проверил с помощью отладочной печати. Проблема в том, что на первом же проходе цикла вы делаете замены **сразу по всему листу** и на следующем цикле уже просто нечего заменять.

Возможно, вам нужно заново загружать файл с шаблоном `wbTemp` на каждой итерации цикла, если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите сделать.

```
Введите количество строк 3
func call
found ,1, исполнитель1
func call
found ,2, 1
func call
found ,3, 01.01.2020
func call
found ,4, 02.02.2020
func call
found ,5, 01.01.2020
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
конец строки
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
конец строки
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
func call
конец строки
end
```

Так будет выглядеть код, если сделать чтение шаблона на каждой итерации. Кроме того, повторяющийся код можно сильно сократить с помощью циклов:

```
#поиск ключей в ФайлШаблон и замена на значения с ФайлсДанными:
for i in range(stroki):
    wbTemp = openpyxl.load_workbook('шаблон.xlsx')
    #открываем лист с данными
    sheet1 = wbTemp['1']
    sheet2 = wbTemp['2']
    for sheet in [sheet1, sheet2]:
        for j in range(1,6):
            find_and_replace(sheet,f',{j},',sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = j).value)
    #сохраняем шаблон как новый файл
    wbTemp.save(str(i+1)+'. '+str(sheetShablon.cell(row=i+2, column = 10).value)+'.xlsx')
    print('конец строки')
    #и так для каждой строки в файле с данными
```

Кроме того, хорошо бы вам как-то поправить имена переменных (либо имена файлов), потому что когда переменная с листом из **файла данных** называется `sheetShablon`, а переменная с файлом-шаблоном называется `wbTemp`, то мозг несколько взрывается, пытаясь понять, где же у вас что - где данные, а где шаблон, чему тут верить - названиям файлов или названиям переменных?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Да вчера осенило в чем проблема. А с переменными действительно пока беда. Будем исправляться